# "Missing collection name" when trying to upload a table to mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark

I'm trying to upload a csv. file I have on HDFS to mongoDB. I'm using a python script for that purpose: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ5W4.png

Using spark 2 and the command: 
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0 cities_mongodb.py

gets me the following error message:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/us4lc.png

I tried searching for missing collection name but didn't find a result. Please note I'm very new to python and don't know the language myself, I'm using a python script from a tutorial with only minor changes. The line .mode('append')\ (which is part of the error message) was already in the script without any changes on my part.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your script and error message as inline code (indent with 4 spaces). Please do not use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the mistake was in the python script. I changed

.option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/worldcities/worldcities")\

to

.option("uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/worldcities.worldcities")\

I just didn't copy from the initial file properly ... Feels kinda awkward. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
./bin/pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
          --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection" \
          --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.1
```

from https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/